# NodeJS Async Callback already called

Tags: node.js, serial-port, async.js

I have been searching but i cannot find what causes this error on my code:

> (node:7672) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Callback was
> already called at C:\Respaldos\SerialReceive\node_modules\async\dist\async.js:966:32
>
> at SerialPort. (C:\Respaldos\SerialReceive\receive.js:35:4)

This is my code:

```
function receiveEnq(callback) {
    port.on('data', function (data) {
        if ((data.length == 1) && (data[0] == 5)) {
            console.log('Received: ENQ');

            return callback(null, 'done');
        } else {
            callback('Error', 'Received:' + data);
        }
    });
}

function sendAck(err, callback) {
    port.write(Buffer.from([6]));
    console.log('Transmitted: ACK');

    callback(null, payload[sequence]);
}

function receiveData(data, callback) {
    port.on('data', function (data) {
        console.log(data);

        callback(null, 'done');
    });
}

async.waterfall([
    receiveEnq,
    sendAck,
    receiveData
], function (err, result) {
    console.log(result)

    if (err) {
        process.abort();
    }
});
```

Can you help me spot the error?

Regards

Comment: Functions like `receiveData()` can call their callback multiple times (every time they get a `data` event), but `async.waterfall()` does not want that to happen.

Comment: Mmmm How can I wait for a response from the serial port before sending new data?

Comment: You can use this model, you just need to design `receiveData()` so that it doesn't call the callback until you're done receiving data and have all the data and thus can call the callback once and only once.  Then, remove the event listener for the `data` event so you won't get notified about any future data.

Comment: I had same problem with async.series , then i have attached return to every callback like return cb(null, 'done'); this solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had to completely rewrite my function. I leave it here in case someone has the same problem

```
const SerialPort = require('serialport');
const ByteLength = SerialPort.parsers.ByteLength;
const port = new SerialPort("COM6");
const parser = new ByteLength({length: 1});
port.pipe(parser);

var state = 0;
var cache = [];
var history;

parser.on('data', function (data) {
    cache.push(data[0]);
    flowcontrol();
});

function porterr() {
    console.log('error');
    process.exit(1);
}

function flowcontrol() {

    switch (state) {

        case 0:
            // Recives 1 byte
            if (cache.length !== 1) {
                return;
            }

            // Sends Answer and changes to next state
            port.write(Buffer.from([6]));
            state++;
            cache.length = 0;
            break;

        case 1:
            // Recives 1 byte
            if (cache.length !== 1) {
                return;
            }

            // Sends Answer and changes to next state
            port.write(Buffer.from([6]));
            state++;
            cache.length = 0;
            break;

        // Define more states here... 
        // .....
        // .....
        // .....

        default:
            console.log('state not defined');
            break;
    }
}
```